# Query only numeric values of the earliest possible date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to query from an `oracle 11` db. 
With the query below I get all recent `TAG_VALUE, TAG_DESC, INSERTION_DATE and PROJECT_ID` from my database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t.tag_value, 
               t.tag_desc, 
               u.update_as_of                    AS INSERTION_DATE, 
               p.proj_id                         AS PROJECT_ID, 
               Row_number() 
                 over( 
                   PARTITION BY p.proj_id 
                   ORDER BY u.update_as_of DESC) RN 
        FROM   project p 
               join update u 
                 ON p.project_id = u.project_id 
               join tag t 
                 ON t.tag_id = u.tag_id 
        WHERE  t.tag_desc LIKE 'Equity%') 
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

However, I came accross the cases that the answer of my request(without sorting it by date) can look like that:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| TAG_VALUE TAG_DESC INSERTION_DATE PROJECT_ID |
+----------------------------------------------+
| null        Equity  14-DEC-14       1        |
| 0           Equity  14-DEC-14       1        |
| 312         Equity  14-DEC-14       1        |
| 23343       Equity  17-DEC-11       5        |
| 1263        Equity  16-DEC-11       5        |
| null        Equity  22-JÄN-14       2        |
| null        Equity  11-JÄN-14       2        |
| null        Equity  25-SEPT-13      2        |
| 0           Equity  20-SEPT-13      2        |
| 1234        Equity  19-SEPT-13      2        |
| 13415       Equity  18-SEPT-13      2        |
| 99999       Equity  16-OCT-10       9        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

My `Result Set` should look like that:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| TAG_VALUE TAG_DESC INSERTION_DATE PROJECT_ID |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 312         Equity  14-DEC-14       1        |
| 23343       Equity  17-DEC-11       5        |
| 1234        Equity  19-SEPT-13      2        |
| 99999       Equity  16-OCT-10       9        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

There are two cases, which basically focus on the same problem:

- As you can see there are two cases, when the `project_id = 1` the insertion date is always the same. However, with my query above I still get `null` back because of the `ordering`. How can I get the number `312` back without getting the `null` or the `0` value?
- If `projectID = 2` there are different Insertion dates and the earlier dates have as `TAG_VALUE` `null` elements. However, I would like to have the `tagValue` of `| 1234        Equity  19-SEPT-13      2        |`, because it is the latest value?

How, can I basically ignore all `null` and also `0` values values and only take the numeric, which is greater than `0` value with the earliest date?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: Can you please correct your query: 
    FROM project p 
    FROM updated u

Comment: Is TAG_VALUE a VARCHAR2 or a NUMBER?  This looks like an EAV model, and if you're using a generic data type the answer will be much more complicated.

Comment: @JonHeller The TAG_Value is NUMERIC. What do you mean by EAV model?

Comment: Entity-Attribute-Value.  It's a common anti-pattern in databases that usually leads to storing all values as strings.  Luckily you haven't fallen for it!  I've seen EAV models before that use those exact same column names, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your grouping happens within PROJECT_ID for INSERTION_DATE DESC and a positive TAG_VALUE, I tweaked the analytical functions to achieve the result. This may not be a robust solution, but will certainly help you.

**Data Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("TAG_VALUE" varchar2(5), "TAG_DESC" varchar2(6), "INSERTION_DATE" varchar2(10), "PROJECT_ID" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES (NULL, 'Equity', '14-DEC-14', 1)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('0', 'Equity', '14-DEC-14', 1)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('312', 'Equity', '14-DEC-14', 1)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('23343', 'Equity', '17-DEC-11', 5)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('1263', 'Equity', '16-DEC-11', 5)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES (NULL, 'Equity', '22-JÄN-14', 2)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES (NULL, 'Equity', '11-JÄN-14', 2)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES (NULL, 'Equity', '25-SEPT-13', 2)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('0', 'Equity', '20-SEPT-13', 2)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('1234', 'Equity', '19-SEPT-13', 2)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('13415', 'Equity', '18-SEPT-13', 2)
    INTO Table1 ("TAG_VALUE", "TAG_DESC", "INSERTION_DATE", "PROJECT_ID")
         VALUES ('99999', 'Equity', '16-OCT-10', 9)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT tag_value, 
       tag_desc, 
       insertion_date, 
       project_id 
FROM   (SELECT tag_value, 
               tag_desc, 
               insertion_date, 
               project_id, 
               Last_value(Decode(tag_value, 0, NULL, 
                                            tag_value) ignore nulls) 
                 over ( 
                   PARTITION BY project_id 
                   ORDER BY insertion_date ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND 
                 unbounded 
                 following ) new_tag_value 
        FROM   table1) 
WHERE  tag_value = new_tag_value;
```

**Result:**

```
TAG_VALUE   TAG_DESC    INSERTION_DATE  PROJECT_ID
312         Equity      14-DEC-14       1
1234        Equity      19-SEPT-13      2
23343       Equity      17-DEC-11       5
99999       Equity      16-OCT-10       9
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/013c3/31)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is: "How, can I basically ignore all null and also 0 values values"

The simple answer is: By removing those records in the WHERE clause.

I use `AND t.tag_value > 0` here. You can replace it with `AND t.tag_value <> 0 AND t.tag_value IS NOT NULL`, if you want to allow negative values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    t.tag_value,
    t.tag_desc, 
    u.update_as_of AS INSERTION_DATE, 
    p.proj_id AS PROJECT_ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.proj_id ORDER BY u.update_as_of DESC) RN
  FROM updated u 
  JOIN project p ON p.project_id = u.project_id  
  JOIN tag t ON t.tag_id = u.tag_id 
  WHERE t.tag_desc LIKE 'Equity%' AND t.tag_value > 0
)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the min(Insertion_Date) and the project ID in an inner query from the table and filter the it by Tag_Value <> Null. Then you in the outer query, inner join the table with this inner query on the project_id and insertion_date.

Comment: Could you please add an example by a sample query? What do you exactly mean by `select the min(Insertion_Date) and the project ID in an inner query from the table and filter the it by Tag_Value <> Null.`

Comment: Select *
from table
join 
(Select PROJECT_ID, min(INSERTION_DATE)
from table
where Tag_Value <> Null
group by project ID)

Comment: Select *
from table t1
join 
(Select PROJECT_ID, min(INSERTION_DATE)
from table 
where Tag_Value <> Null
group by project ID) t2
on t1.Project_id = t2.project_id
and t1.insertion_date = t2.insertion_date


the "table" here can be your actual table or the select statement you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Use case 1:**

If I understood your use cases correctly, you can do it via "prioritization" of the non-null-non-zero `tag_value`-s in your analytic function's ordering clause as follows:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY p.proj_id
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN t.tag_value > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
        u.update_as_of DESC
) RN
```

This, of course, will give you `null`-s or zeroes in your output everytime there are no other `tag_value`-s in your data partition identified by the `p.proj_id`.

---

**Use case 2:**

If you want to get rid of the zeroes and `null`-s completely, you'll have to modify the `where` clause of your (inner) query instead:

```
WHERE t.tag_desc LIKE 'Equity%'
    AND t.tag_value > 0
```